# Apache: Redirect everything from www to non-www using https only (including HSTS)

Tags: apache-2.4, http, https, 301-redirect

#### My goal

Everything results in `https://mydomain.tld` (*non-www and with TLS*) and HSTS works correct. I am using the certificates from LE (Let's Encrypt) and so I used their wizard to make my website HTTPS everywhere. But it doesn't seem to work correct.

#### My current problems

1. Visiting `http://mydomain.tld` (*non-www, non-tls*). The result is
   the Apache-status-page, but I already have a website running with
   content. Reloading the page results in `https://mydomain.tld` with
   website-content. But it should do that from the first vist on and
   not only after reloading the page.
2. Visiting `http://www.mydomain.tld` results in
   `https://www.mydomain.tld` which is okay from TLS-view, but it
   doesn't redirect to non-www, which is my goal.
3. Visiting `https://www.mydomain.tld` resuslts in
   `https://www.mydomain.tld`. No redirection to non-www.
4. **No problem:** Visiting `https://mydomain.tld` results in the same URL, which is what I want.

**DNS-settings:**

```
A-RECORDS
.mydomain.tld -> 111.222.333.444
*.mydomain.tld -> 111.222.333.444
www.mydomain.tld -> 111.222.333.444
```

**mydomain.tld.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName mydomain.tld
ServerAlias www.mydomain.tld
ServerAdmin contact@mydomain.tld
DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.tld/public_html
Redirect permanent / https://mydomain.tld/

<Directory /var/www/mydomain.tld/public_html>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

**mydomain.tld-le-ssl.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName www.mydomain.tld
        ServerAlias mydomain.tld
        ServerAdmin contact@mydomain.tld
        DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.tld/public_html

        <Directory /var/www/mydomain.tld/public_html>
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains; preload"

RewriteEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.tld/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.tld/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

As you can see above in the **mydomain.tld-le-ssl.conf** another file is included, which might doesn't make problems, but just for the records:

**options-ssl-apache.conf**

```
# Baseline setting to Include for SSL sites

SSLEngine on

# Intermediate configuration, tweak to your needs
SSLProtocol             all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLCipherSuite          ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA$
SSLHonorCipherOrder     on
SSLCompression          off

SSLOptions +StrictRequire

# Add vhost name to log entries:
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%v %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" vhost_common

#CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log vhost_combined
#LogLevel warn
#ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

# Always ensure Cookies have "Secure" set (JAH 2012/1)
#Header edit Set-Cookie (?i)^(.*)(;\s*secure)??((\s*;)?(.*)) "$1; Secure$3$4"
```

---

## Bonus-problem

I have a `.htaccess`-file in my domain-root which makes the links look better:

- without: `https://mydomain.tld/index.php?page=news`
- with: `https://mydomain.tld/news`

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^\w+$ index.php?page=$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]
```

I would like to live without the .htaccess-file and add the stuff to the .conf-file(s) if possible, but everything I did, didn't work yet.

Answer (score 0):

It's weird. Yesterday I created new certs and it still worked. Today:

- Chrome (mobile): `http://mydomain.tld` redirects correct to
  `https://mydomain.tld`
- Firefox (desktop): `http://mydomain.tld`
  doesn't redirect and results in Apache-page
- Firefox (mobile) which never was on my website: Same as Firefox
  (desktop)
- Safari (mobile) which never was on my website: Same as Firefox
  (desktop)

So, it seems there is still a problem. Would be great to get help to solve this finally.

## Solution for this problem:

- $ `sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf`
- Remove the stuff below in mydomain.tld.conf:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/%$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,QSA,R=permanent]`

Just use: `Redirect permanent / https://mydomain.tld`

- $`sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 restart`

### Final files

**mydomain.tld.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName mydomain.tld
ServerAlias www.mydomain.tld
ServerAdmin contact@mydomain.tld
DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.tld/public_html
Redirect permanent / https://mydomain.tld

<Directory /var/www/mydomain.tld/public_html>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**mydomain.tld-le-ssl.conf**

```
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so

<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomain$

ServerName mydomain.tld
ServerAlias www.mydomain.tld
ServerAdmin contact@nmydomain.tld
DocumentRoot /var/www/mydomain.tld/public_html

<Directory /var/www/mydomain.tld/public_html>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Require all granted

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^\w+$ index.php?page=$0 [L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} index\.php
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=(\w+)$
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ /%1? [R=301,L]

</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.tld/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.tld/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: It's good to know that you found the solution for most issues. Why not mark it as the correct answer?